# Gitlab can't find gradle even though it exists

Tags: android, gradle, ionic-framework, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to build an android apk through gitlab.yml and everything works until I call gradle.

It gives me the error command not found even though gradle exists in the folder
What am I doing wrong?

Here is my script

sign_android:

```
  image: openjdk:8-jdk
  stage: sign
  script:
    - cd android
    - ls
    - gradle
    - gradlew
    - ./gradlew
    - gradle build
```

Here is the ouput

```
cd android
$ ls
app
build.gradle
capacitor-cordova-android-plugins
capacitor.settings.gradle
gradle
gradle.properties
gradlew
gradlew.bat
local.properties
settings.gradle
variables.gradle
$ gradle
/bin/bash: line 167: gradle: command not found
```

Comment: Did you try to run gradlew instead of the gradle?

Comment: Just call `./gradlew build`

Answer (score 0):

you can define the full PATH for it, like this -

```
sign_android:
  image: openjdk:8-jdk
  stage: sign
  script:
    - cd android
    - ls
    - export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/gradle/bin"
    - gradle build
```

also i'll recommend you to first check gradle version before doing this just make sure whether gradle is installed or not.

Comment: alternatively you can also run ./gradlew build before gradle, lmk if it helped.

Comment: unfortunately I dont have a gradle/bin folder. 
I do have a gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar 
but that is all I have

Comment: in that case just do this instead - ./gradlew build